# Can you retrieve a list of valid arguments to a function in Python

Tags: python, nltk

I am using the nltk library for python, more specifically the corpus stopwords, and I would like to ensure that the language passed to the `nltk.corpus.stopwords.words()` function is a valid language entry according to the list.

My question is, is there a way for me to retrieve a list of the valid arguments that can be provided to this function?

Comment: Did you try `help()`?

Comment: I suspect the list is here, but I need to check a bit to be sure. https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/europarl_raw.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to where you downloaded the stopwords (by default `~/nltk_data/corpora/stopwords`).

Each file in this index is a list of stopwords, and is referred to by name in the `corpus.stopwords.words` function.

Because they're plain text files, it's easy to modify them or add your own.

---

If you just want to not crash, maybe

```
language = 'blahblah'
try:
    words = ntlk.corpus.stopwords.words(language)
except OSError:
    print('invalid language', language)
```

Comment: Is there a way to check against this list at runtime, for example if I were to supply a language not supported, can I check this without terminating the program with an error?

Comment: Yes, set `possible = os.listdir('/home/{ddg}/corpora/stopwords')` for a list of files, then check with `language in possible`.

Comment: Substituting out the username ("ddg") for your own